# Parallax scrolling start at specific height

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I trying to implement parallax scrolling to my website. This works almost perfect. What the problem is, is that I would like to have a parallax section almost at the bottom. When I am scrolling down, is the image that I have set as background image further above, like this:
[image]

The photo should already stop at the begin of the gray section, you see bellow.

My code:

```
// Can also be used with $(document).ready() / $(window).load()
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Cache the Window object
    $window = $(window);

    $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
    var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object

        $(window).scroll(function() {

            // Scroll the background at var speed
            // the yPos is a negative value because we're scrolling it UP!                              
            var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed')); 

            // Put together our final background position
            var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

            // Move the background
            $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });

        }); // window scroll Ends

    }); 

    });
```

Below the HTML markup:

```
<section class="quote" id="quote-home" data-speed="4" data-type="background">
    <div class="container_12">
        <header class="grid_12 centered">
            <h1>
            The beginning of knowlegde
            <br>
            is the discovery of something 
            <br>
            we do not understand.”
            </h1>

            <span class="cross-x"></span>

            <h2>- Frank Herbert</h2>
        </header><!-- End header.grid_12 --> 

    <div class="clear"></div><!-- End div.clear -->
    </div><!-- End div.container_12 -->
</section><!-- End section#quote -->

<section id="twitter" class="alt">
```

And the css:

```
#quote-home {
    height: 500px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 100%; 
    position: relative; 
    background: url(../images/coffeescripthands.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

Comment: To clarify, your problem is that the background image is too high when you scroll all the way down?

Comment: @JordanTrudgett Exactly. So the image should scroll above, a little lately.

Comment: If you have a site or a jsFiddle demo you can link to that shows this, that would help to verify a solution

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on exactly what you want, what you have, and why it isn't working. A working example of what you have may help too.

Comment: I edited the JavaScript quickly to do this http://puu.sh/2WPTm/34895c3a42.png and it looks better, maybe you can use something like that

Comment: @JordanTrudgett, is there a formula to math the height of that yPos, so it will automatically stop when the image top is reached. ?

Comment: That may be a better question to ask. ;)